# How to find difference between 2 columns in R of a vector?

Tags: r, probability

I have the following vector in R

```
x <-seq(1, 10, by=1)    
p <-permutations(10, 3, c(x), repeats.allowed=FALSE)
```

I would like to list all the rows that have difference between first and last column less than 3. How can I achieve this in R?

I know that I can get the first and third column using this but i dont know after that:

```
p[, c(1,3)]
```

Thank you for any direction

Comment: What package is `permutations` in? In any event, you probably want something like `which(abs(p[,1]-p[,3]) < 3)`

Comment: its the gtool package. I tried this command but it gives me a big table of random values. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
new_p <- p[p[, 1] - p[, 3] < 3, ]
```